# How to get only one drop down enabled out of two if out of two choices one is met at a time in MS Access 2007 form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to MS Access and making a database for my plant maintenance. I have two choices i.e. Breakdown or Job order. I should select either of one. Then I make two drop downs, one is maintenance request name and another is Job order request name. The question is, If I select maintenance choice above, then I should go directly to maintenance request name drop down and in that case Job order request name drop down should be disable.

Kindly advise suitable solution. Please let me know if the above information is sufficient.

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In the After Update event for the maintenance choice, add a little code.

```
 Me.JobOrderDropdownName.Enabled = False
 Me.MaintenanceDropdownName.Enabled = True
 Me.MaintenanceDropdownName.SetFocus
```

And similarly for the Job Order choice. This could be simplified if you have created an option group for the two choices.

Comment: Or he/she may use the (Combobox) Click event.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean If you mean run the above code in the combo click event, no, that would not work. If you mean wait until the user reaches the maintenance combo to tell them that they cannot use it, that seems unfair.

Comment: It's a misunderstanding. OP's approach suppose two clicks. Instead, if he/she uses only those two COMBOBOXs/DROPDOWNLISTs (and remove OPTION controls), the user will have to use only one click (COMBOBOX). Of course, in this case, the source code will be different (another events - GotFocus/LostFocus- and another statements/actions). Ex: the combobox (Combo0) wich becomes active can change his background color: `Private Sub Combo0_GotFocus(): Combo0.BackColor = vbYellow: Combo2.BackColor = vbWhite: End Sub`.